# Extracting data from a Table (MarkLogic)

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-optic-api

I am currently trying to extract data out from a table to use it as a list of URI's for a XQuery CTS Search. Currently, I have created a optics query which returns data in a table-like format.

For example through using the following Optics query

```
import module namespace op="http://marklogic.com/optic" at "/MarkLogic/optic.xqy";
import module namespace ofn="http://marklogic.com/optic/expression/fn" at "/MarkLogic/optic/optic-fn.xqy";


let $people := op:from-sparql('SELECT * WHERE {?person </id> "000". ?person </path> ?animal}', "sparql")
                => op:select(( op:as('personStr',ofn:string(op:col('person'))), op:as('animalStr',ofn:string(op:col('animal'))) ))


return(
$people => op:result()
)
```

I will retrieve a table that looks like

```
personStr      |    animalStr
-------------------------------
/people/000         /animal/001
/people/000         /animal/002
```

Within this table will contain URI pointing to various documents, which I hope to extract (animalStr for instance) from and do some filtering through the usage of `cts:search(fn:doc(uri_list), ....)`

===Update with Current Approach===

```
let $people := op:from-sparql('SELECT * WHERE {?person </id> "000". ?person </path> ?animal}', "sparql")
                => op:select(( op:as('personStr',ofn:string(op:col('person'))), op:as('animalStr',ofn:string(op:col('animal'))) ))

let $animal := op:from-lexicons(
  map:entry("animal",cts:uri-reference()),
  "lexicon")
  =>op:where(
     cts:path-geospatial-query("animal_data/location",
    cts:circle(5500, cts:point(-55.854526273011, -151.93342455372309)),
    "type=long-lat-point")
  )

return(
$animal  => op:join-inner(
    $people,
    op:on(
      "animal","animalStr"
    )
  )
  => op:select(("personStr", "animalStr"))
  => op:result()
)
```

Based on this approach it can be seen that I am always required to retrieve all animals within a certain location before performing an inner-join to get my results. However, ideally I would like to apply the geospatial query directly to the results retrieved from the SPARQL query.

Comment: What is your actual question? Do you want to know whether your current approach is the right one?

Comment: I am willing to accept other alternative approaches to this if there are any of them. I have updated my question in an attempt to explain what I am trying to actually achieve. But in general I would like to filter a optic sparql query directly using geospatial queries to retrieve all animals within a certain geospatial space using `cts:circle` directly. @Wagner Micheal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optic can constrain a SPARQL query to the triples projected from documents that match a dynamic query including those documents matched by geospatial cts queries.

The general pattern is:

```
op.fromSparql(...SPARQL query...)
  .where(...cts query...)
```

While the builder specifies the cts.query after the SPARQL query, the engine doesn't execute those steps sequentially. Instead, the engine ignores all triples from documents that don't match the cts.query.

A constraining cts.query works the same way for rows and lexicon values.

In fact, supplying a constraining cts.query with a where() clause is a best practice for improving the efficiency of retrieval.  That's especially true for triples because triples are by definition join intensive.

Is it possible that this pattern can meet the requirement?

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Thanks it seems to work. But I would like to ask if this applies to all other other variations such as `op:from-view`? Additionally, how does it work if I chain a `cts query` with `op:where` after performing `op:join-inner` operation with other tables/results? @ehennum

Comment: Yes, a constraining cts:query works with all accessors including op:from-view(), op:from-lexicons() and op:from-triples().  If a where() operation specifies a constraining cts:query after a join, the query applies to both sides of the join. That is, only  values from documents matched by the query contribute to both sides of the join.

Comment: I see I would like to clarify to use `op:from-view()` we will need to project documents into a `view` with SQL-like tables allowing the data to be queried using `SQL`, so when we run `cts queries` with `op:where` are we filtering away `documents` rather then the `view` itself. Hence documents that do not meet the `cts query` requirements will not be displayed in the view. This also applies to `op:from-sparql` as it will filter both triple documents and documents that project triples using Template Driven Extraction. @ehennum

Comment: Yes, @WhiteSolstice, that's right.  The TDE projects rows or triples from  a document into the indexes when the document is inserted or reindexed. The constraining cts:query matches the documents in the same way as with cts:search().  Where cts:search() retrieves the matched documents from the forest or cache, the Optic from-view(), from-triples(), from-lexicons(), from-sparql(), and from-sql() accessors retrieve the values for the matched documents from the indexes.